# Gradle: No candidates found for method call

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and Gradle 7.3.3 to create a Kotlin library multiplatform, but I have the nexts errors with gradle compilation: **No candidates found for method call...**, in command-line compile good.

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.6.10'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    **jvm** {
        **compilations**.all {
            **kotlinOptions**.jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
        **withJava**()
        **testRuns**["test"].executionTask.configure {
            **useJUnitPlatform**()
        }
    }
    **js**(**BOTH**) {
        **browser** {
            **commonWebpackConfig** {
                **cssSupport**.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
    def hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    def isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    def nativeTarget
    if (hostOs == "Mac OS X") nativeTarget = **macosX64**('native')
    else if (hostOs == "Linux") nativeTarget = **linuxX64**("native")
    else if (isMingwX64) nativeTarget = **mingwX64**("native")
    else throw new GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")

    
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {

        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test')
            }
        }
        jvmMain {

        }
        jvmTest {

        }
        jsMain {

        }
        jsTest {

        }
        nativeMain {

        }
        nativeTest {

        }
    }
}
```

All inside ** ... ** have the next problem: No candidates found for method call...

I try Invalidate Caches/Restart..., re-install IntelliJ, re-import Gradle, etc.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is the problem IDE only? Can you reproduce it with Gradle build? What version of IDE and Kotlin IDE plugin do you use?